# How can a client make use of expires_in?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Observing OAuth2, `expires_in` seems to be a common parameter returned alongside an access token. The value of `expires_in` is the number of seconds remaining until the access token expires. I'm having trouble seeing how client applications would be able to make use of this in a convenient way. Expecting clients to count down the seconds after receiving an access token seems annoying at best. Wouldn't it be easier to set something like `expires_at` with a future timestamp when it expires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposal of `expires_at` would be almost impossible to manage when client and server are not synchronized in time. But if I'm wrong, please, correct me.

You have two options here:

- Calculate if the token has expired by subtracting the `expires_in` seconds and the seconds spent from where you requested the token until now.
- Get the token info (`/oauth/tokeninfo`, `/tokens/{token}`, or whatever, depending on the OAuth2 provider, and check if it is still valid and has not expired.

Both approaches have clear pros and cons, but I do, personally, prefer the second one.